# My TableViewCell won't change its height according to the dynamically changing view inside of it

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have tried using UITableView.automaticDimension for both the heightForRowAt and for the estimatedHeightForRowAt with the same results of the cell not changing with a dynamically changing view.

Here is some relevant code:

From the view controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   // return getSize(large: 70, medium: 60, small: 50)
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

From the tableview cell:

```
func setup(_ lineItem: MenuItem) {
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    configureTransactionView(lineItem)
    configureItemNameLabel(lineItem)
    configurePriceLabel(lineItem)
    configureSizeLabel(lineItem)
}

private func configureTransactionView(_ lineItem: MenuItem) {
    itemView = UIView()
    guard let itemView = itemView else { return }
    itemView.clipsToBounds = true
    itemView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    itemView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    itemView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    itemView.backgroundColor = .white
    contentView.addSubview(itemView)
    itemView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    itemView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    itemView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
    itemView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    let fontSize = getSize(large: 14, medium: 13.5, small: 12)
    guard let topFont = UIFont(name: AppFont.secondary.name, size: fontSize) else { return }
    let heightForTopLabel = heightForView(text: lineItem.name, font: topFont, width: 195)
    var text = ""
    if lineItem.quantity > 1 && lineItem.toppings != nil {
        text = generateTextWithMultipleSelected(lineItem)
    } else if lineItem.quantity > 1 {
        if lineItem.size != nil {
            guard let size = lineItem.size else { return }
            text = "\(size) | Quantity: \(lineItem.quantity)"
        } else {
            text = "Quantity: \(lineItem.quantity)"
        }
    } else if lineItem.toppings != nil {
        text = generateTextWithSingleSelected(lineItem)
    } else {
        if lineItem.size != nil {
            guard let size = lineItem.size else { return }
            text = "\(size)"
        } else {
            text = ""
        }
    }
    let bottomFontSize = getSize(large: 11, medium: 10.5, small: 9.5)
    guard let font = UIFont(name: AppFont.secondary.name, size: bottomFontSize) else { return }
    let heightForBottomLabel = heightForView(text: text, font: font, width: 200)
    let height = heightForTopLabel + heightForBottomLabel + 10
    itemView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your TableViewController viewDidLoad() add the following:

```
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600 //change according to your needs
```

Also remove heightForRowAtIndexPath and estimetedHeightForRowAtIndexPath methods.

Here is a good turtorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells